# Find an easy and quick way to solve parameter integral vs. why is it so hard to find a solution?

Tags: calculus, integration

I just found a question which seems to be very hard in solving (for me), but was given in a written exam and had to be solved in short time. The question is: given two functions $f,g$ with following definitions: $$f(x):=\bigg(\int_0^x\textrm{e}^{-t^2}\mathrm{d}t\bigg)^2
$$ and
$$
g(x):=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x^2(1+s^2)}}{1+s^2}\mathrm{d}s
$$ Show that $f,g$ are differentiable and that $f'(x)+g'(x)=0$.
So my idea for solving this, when beginning with $g(x)$ to show, that $g'(x)$ can be solved with Leibniz-Rule, so I find: $$
K(x,s)= \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x^2(1+s^2)}}{1+s^2}\mathrm{d}s
$$ and $$
D_1K(x)=-2x\mathrm{e}^{-x^2(1+s^2)}
$$ So far, so good, and until yet there are no problems. For finding the derivative of $f(x)$ now we have to solve the new integral$$
g'(x)=\int D_1K(x,s)\mathrm{d}s=\int_0^1-2x\mathrm{e}^{-x^2(1+s^2)}\mathrm{d}s=-2x\int_0^1\mathrm{e}^{-x^2(1+s^2)}\mathrm{d}s
$$and the problem arises. It may be very easy, when the integral was with $s$ instead of $s^2$, but I have no clue how to solve this in limited time in an exam.

But what about $f(x)$. It's very similar to a famous Gauss-Integral, isn't it, and here we can use the chain rule for derivatives:$$
f'(x)=2\int_0^x\mathrm{e}^{-t^2}\mathrm{d}t\,\,\mathrm{e}^{-y^2}=2\mathrm{e}^{-y^2}\int_0^x\mathrm{e}^{-t^2}\mathrm{d}t
$$
I had several attemps trying to find the solution for $f'(x)=g'(x)$. I'm not really looking for the solution as itself, but I would appreciate any help to find one. We have only Calculus 2 niveau and we do not use polynomial series or something like that. I think there must be a solution that can be held within some minutes as this was "only" a written exam question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's work with your calculations. So, you got that:
$$g'(x) = -2x \int_{0}^{1} \exp(-x^2(1+s^2)) \ ds$$

Now, observe that:
$$\exp(-x^2(1+s^2)) = \exp(-x^2) \exp(-x^2s^2)$$
Since the first term in the product is independent of $s$, we can just write:
$$g'(x) = -2x \exp(-x^2) \int_{0}^{1} \exp(-x^2s^2) \ ds$$Let $u =xs$. Then, $du = x \ ds$. So:
$$x\int_{0}^{1} \exp(-x^2s^2) \ ds =  \int_{0}^{x} \exp(-u^2) \ du$$
In other words, it follows that:
$$g'(x) = -2\exp(-x^2) \int_{0}^{x} \exp(-u^2) \ du = -f'(x)$$
which proves the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, now I understand how to handle those problems. THANK YOU :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that$$
g'(x)=-2x\int_0^1\mathrm{e}^{-x^2(1+s^2)}ds
\overset{s=t/x}= -2\int_0^x\mathrm{e}^{-x^2-t^2}dt=-f’(x)
$$

Comment: Wow, wonderful. Very short, and understandable. Thank you!